# Using jQuery for vertical and horizontal centering

Tags: jquery, center

I'm using jQuery to horizontally center a div element that doesn't have a default width. I'm using the following code, but it's not working. if anyone could help me to understand why, it'd be very helpful. PS, I the height has a default height of 20, so that's where the -10px comes from.

```
var w = ($(".notec").width() + 51) / 2;
$(".buttons").css("margin", "-10px 0 0 -" + w + "px");
```

Comment: _"James here"_ **?!** Stackoverflow isn't your personal blog...

Comment: James, that kind of attitude, especially when you are just 13yrs old, wouldn't help.

Comment: @xForty Attitude is not dependent on age. James, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128552/102937 as a reference for gdoron's comment.

Comment: @RobW, yes you are right, but I was pointing "yet another" factor.

Answer (score 0):

Centering with respect to `.notec`. Width is not needed if the element is displaying as block element.

```
var h = ($(".notec").height() - $(".buttons").height()) / 2;
$(".buttons").css("margin", h+"px auto 0 auto');
```

Comment: @JamesCharless, With what I am given... I cant do much. Post a fiddle with your code, I can hack to.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at: UI/API/1.8/Position http://bit.ly/IvUhLF

```
$(".overlay").hide();
$(".photo_hold").hover(
  function () {
      $(".overlay", $(this)).show();
      $(".buttons", $(this)).position({
          my: "center",
          at: "center",
          of: $(this)
      });
   },
  function () {
      $(".overlay", $(this)).hide();
  }
);
```

play with the variables to make it do what you need

Comment: I was not aware of this method. It's not working though. http://jamestestblog3.tumblr.com/ Take a look (hover over the photos, the div the buttons are in is called .buttons and the div the .buttons are in is .photo_hold)

Comment: you have to add a reference to jqueryUI - http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: having multiple instances of buttons and notec, you cannot use css selectors because there's no way to reference a parent element, so you have to be a little bit more clever and use javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9JdP/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10663/discussion-between-smnbss-and-jamescharless)